# "cannot allocate memory block" using R plot.phylo

Tags: r, genetics, phylogeny

I'm pretty new to R, and am trying to plot a phylogenetic tree with 75 tips and 73 internal nodes (for the first time). I have genotype data for 4567 SNPs.

When I try to plot the data, I get the following error message:

```
> plot(tre, type = "fan", use.edge.length = TRUE, node.pos = NULL, 
    show.tip.label = TRUE, show.node.label = FALSE, edge.color = "black", 
    edge.width = 1, edge.lty = 1, font = 3, cex = 0.3, adj = NULL, srt = 0, 
    no.margin = FALSE, root.edge = FALSE, label.offset = 0, underscore = FALSE, 
    x.lim = NULL, y.lim = NULL, direction = "rightwards", lab4ut = NULL, 
    tip.color = "black", plot = TRUE, rotate.tree = 0, open.angle = 0, 
    node.depth = 1, align.tip.label = FALSE)


Error in reorder.phylo(x, order = "postorder") : 
  cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 *Tb*
```

What am I doing wrong here? It can't possibly need this amount of memory

Comment: Can you show at least a summary of your data? Have you tried plotting a tree on a subset of your data?

Comment: The memory issue is in Tb, so a subset is definitely necessary. I'm also curious how you got the data in (thinking the inflation shouldn't be that extensive) and why the plotting function is inflating the size of the data so much.

Comment: I have 2 data files: a csv file containing 2 columns (IDs and collection dates), for 273 individuals (size 6.91 KB). And a fasta file of the alignment of core snps, for 75 individuals, each of 4567 nucleotides in length (4567 snps, file size 335 KB). Nothing particularly huge I would have thought, but then it's my first go at it.

Comment: Ok, the source of the problem seems to be when I try and change the tip labels of my tree: treeroot1ladd$tip.label <- paste("Case ",1:75, " / day ", days, sep = "", collapse = NULL)

Comment: Ok, the source of the problem seems to be when I try and change the tip labels of my tree: treeroot1ladd$tip.label <- paste("Case ",1:75, " / day ", days, sep = "", collapse = NULL). I get an error message that is beyond me to puzzle out: Error in if (tabulate(phy$edge[, 1])[length(phy$tip.label) + 1] > 2) FALSE else TRUE : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong to get this error message? I only have the memory block size error when I try to change tip labels - it's fine otherwise

Comment: I probably should add: the full error message is 'Error in reorder.phylo(x, order = "postorder") : 
  cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb
In addition: Warning message:
In yy[TIPS] <- 1:Ntip :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length'